# Manejo de Handler y Runnable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, callback

Tengo en mi código un simple Handler que realiza la acción de cerrar todas las Activities anteriores y enviar al usuario de vuelta al MainActivity. El código es el siguiente:

```
 public class Base extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    ...
    Handler mHandler =  new Handler();
    Runnable updateRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             checkProcess();
           }
      };
   }
```

Tenemos el método `checkProcess()`:

```
  public void checkProcess() {
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        //Intent Clear Task/New task
        startActivity(i);
  }
```

Corremos el proceso en alguna Activity X si se queda en segundo plano o en la misma pantalla durante cierto tiempo:

```
 mHandler.postDelayed(updateRunnable, 60000 * 5);
```

El método del handler es llamado despues de haber transcurrido cinco minutos, y funciona correctamente. El problema viene cuando quiero detener el proceso. Tengo un botón que al hacer click debería cancelar el Task que se ha iniciado, hay alguna forma de que el Handler detenga un proceso que ya está corriendo?

He probado con:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(updateRunnable)
```

Pero no funciona. El Task sigue corriendo y al llegar a los 5 minutos me lleva de nuevo al MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

removeCallbacks(updateRunnable)`efectivamente cancelara la ejecucion del runnable el problema es que estas creando un`handler`y un`runnable`por cada activity que herede de`Base`.
Si creaste el Activity1 y Activity2 que heredan de Base vas a tener 2 handlers esperando para ejecutar el runnable. cuando vos desde el Activity2 ejecutes el`removeCallbacks` este va a cancelar solo la ejecucion de un runnable no de ambos.

Podes solucionarlo haciendo static al handler y runnable asi solo tenes uno de cada uno sin importar cuantos Activities crees. Tambien deberias quitar la inicializacion de runnable del onCreate porque sino se va a pisar el runnable con cada Activity que se cree.

```
public class Base extends AppCompatActivity {
...
...
static Handler mHandler =  new Handler();
static Runnable updateRunnable = updateRunnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      checkProcess();
   }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
```

Seguramente tambien tendras que modificar el checkProcess para que ejecute como metodo de clase y tener cuidado con la perdida de contexto.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @Erick la verdad me aclaró un poco las dudas. Con respecto a modificar el checkProcess efectivamente el método non-static no puede ser referenciado desde un static context. Como podría modificar el método para el funcionamiento correcto?